# Show whether the GUI is running or not in matlab GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm currently creating a GUI using mathlab GUIDE. Since the GUI is very slow I'd like to add an `edit_text` uicontrol in order to show whether the GUI is running or not.

For instance I have a `push_button` that changes the plot in an axes. When the user click on this button the GUI takes several seconds to perform the new plot. What I want to do is setting the `edit_text` with the string `'running'` as soon as the button was pressed. When the callback is done and the plot plotted I'd like to set the `edit_text` with another string : `'ready'`.

I used the following code :

```
function push_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to push_button (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

set(handles.edit_text,'String','Running...');
%a bunch of code...
set(handles.edit_text,'String','Ready.');
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

I hoped that once the callback is called, the GUI would display `'running...'` on my `edit_text`. Apparently I was wrong. When running the GUI and pressing the `push_button` the plot changes but the `edit_text` remains the same.

Then I tried something else using the `ButtonDownFcn` callback. My idea was that the latter callback would be executed *before* the actual callback (written above). Here is the code :

```
function push_button_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to push_button (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

set(handles.edit_text,'String','Running...');
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

The problem is that the `ButtonDownFcn` callback isn't executed every time. As GUIDE says about the latter callback :

```
% --- If Enable == 'on', executes on mouse press in 5 pixel border.
% --- Otherwise, executes on mouse press in 5 pixel border or over str22.
```

Obviously I want my `push_button` to be enabled, otherwise it won't work the way I want. So I don't know what else to try.

Has someone any idea how I could manage to do that ?

Comment: In your original attempt, `edit_text` should indeed display "running..." when the callback starts. I would try to investigate why this is not happening. Perhaps a the command `drawnow`, after the first `set`, would force the GUI to redraw itself and update the `edit_text` string.

Comment: @SamRoberts It worked. Thank you very much. Well, it was pretty simple after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing

```
set(handles.edit_text,'String','Running...');
drawnow;
%a bunch of code...
```

The GUI might not be updated until you get to

```
set(handles.edit_text,'String','Ready.');
```

So forcing it to update with drawnow might work for you.